# CSS Active Button

Tags: c#, html, css

I have the html code

```
asp:Button ID="btnStartExportRPT" EnableTheming="true" CssClass="ButtonFilterSelectionL"
                                    Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResources, cmdStartExecute %>" runat="server"/>
```

and I have the css

```
.ButtonFilterSelectionL
{
    font-family: Segoe UI, Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    color: #999999;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.ButtonFilterSelectionL:active
{
    font-family: Segoe UI, Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    color: #005C8B;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and in my C# code I have defined after some functions

```
 btnStartExportRPT.Enabled = true;
```

I want to know how can I use the `.ButtonFilterSelectionL:active` css?

Comment: Do you see the font color change when you click the button? Are you perhaps looking for :hover or :focus states isntead of the :active?

Comment: Changing `.ButtonFilterSelectionL:active` to `.ButtonFilterSelectionL:active, .ButtonFilterSelectionL:hover` will apply the CSS when you hover on the button.

Comment: As a side note you don't need to re-declare your all your styles because they will be inherited from `.ButtonFilterSelectionL`.  You only need to add any rules you want to override like `color`

Comment: when  add the hover , as I move the cursor overit it changes to blue, but I don't want it to be blue till it's active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I should have used `.ButtonFilterSelectionL:enabled` instead of .`ButtonFilterSelectionL:active`